# Split polygon by MultiLineString - shapely

Tags: python, polygon, shapely, splitting

I'm working on splitting a polygon given a set of linestrings using the shapely python library. The problem I'm facing is that a polygon cannot be split by a MultiLineString using`shapely.ops.split(geom, splitter)`. [image]

The desired result in the image above is to split polygon (blue) with the linestrings (yellow, brown, red) and recieve 4 seperate polygons (1,2,3,4). The geometries in the image are provided below. It is preferred to do this within shapely.

```
    polygon = shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon(
[(172288.6111791851, 442085.8603492165),
 (172300.89001713035, 442131.53561756504),
 (171916.83106749243, 442140.9016841368),
 (171910.779533863, 442014.47234046715),
 (172165.44614826166, 442016.17982713436),
 (172188.0201264064, 442022.13092037174),
 (172189.32585150487, 442047.592559792),
 (172159.87170649506, 442049.9277989104),
 (172169.13733267464, 442085.8603492165),
 (172288.6111791851, 442085.8603492165)])

coords = [((172159.87170649506, 442016.14245166205),
 (172159.87170649506, 442049.9277989104)),((172159.87170649506, 442049.9277989104),
 (172159.87170649506, 442134.97463880514)),((172169.13733267464, 442085.8603492165),
 (172169.13733267464, 442134.74867747363))]

lines = shapely.geometry.MultiLineString(coords)
```

Comment: Thanks for the question. This cellular decomposition approach should be in the Robotics network of Stack Exchange

Answer (score 10, accepted):

adopted the answer from this post: [Splitting Polygon by Linestring in GeoDjango?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/232771/splitting-polygon-by-linestring-in-geodjango).

```
line_split_collection.append(polygon.boundary) # collection of individual linestrings for splitting in a list and add the polygon lines to it.
merged_lines = shapely.ops.linemerge(line_split_collection)
border_lines = shapely.ops.unary_union(merged_lines)
decomposition = shapely.ops.polygonize(border_lines)
```

The lines for splitting are slightly extended in both directions (0.01) in order to ensure that they cross the input polygon border, therefore making the unary_union work.