# Convert Linestrings from OSMnx into Multipolygon

Tags: python, shapely, osmnx

I'm retrieving some geometries from OpenStreetMap with OSMnx library with the following code:

```
G = ox.graph_from_place('Casco Viejo, Bilbao, Spain', network_type='walk', 
                        retain_all=True, buffer_dist = 50, which_result = 2,
                        infrastructure = 'relation["highway" = "pedestrian"]')
```

which yields the following graph composed by shapely linestrings:

[image]

Then I convert the graph into a geopandas geodataframe:

```
ped = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes = False)
```

I've tried this to convert `Linestrings` to `Points` and then `Points` to `Multipolygon`

Is there a way to convert this linestrings into a shapely `Multipolygon`:

```
from shapely import geometry, ops

# combine them into a multi-linestring
multi_line = geometry.MultiLineString(list(ped['geometry']))

merged_line = ops.linemerge(multi_line)

from shapely.geometry import Point, MultiPoint

points = []
for i in range(0, len(merged_line)):
    points.append((Point(list(merged_line[i].coords[1]))))

coords = [p.coords[:][0] for p in points]

poly = Polygon(coords)
```

This yields a weird wrong geometry:

```
shape(poly)
```

If I try:

```
MultiPolygon(points)
```

It gives this Error Message: `TypeError: 'Point' object is not subscriptable`

Is there a way to transform `Linestrings` into `Multipolygon` and this into `GeoDataFrame`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you need to use [unary_union](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.ops.unary_union) and [polygonize](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#shapely.ops.polygonize) (see [Split polygon by MultiLineString - shapely](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/312215/2581))

```
....
ped = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes = False)
from shapely.ops import unary_union, polygonize
multi_line = ped.geometry.values
border_lines = unary_union(multi_line)
result = MultiPolygon(polygonize(border_lines))
```

The resulting polygons

[image]

[image][image]

#### New

To fix the issue of holes, a solution is to retain only the polygons with holes

```
polys = []
result = list(ops.polygonize(border_lines))
for poly in result:
    if len(poly.interiors) >= 1: # only polygon with holes
        polys.append(poly)
```

In one line:

```
polys = [poly for poly in result if len(poly.interiors) >= 1]
```

Only two polygons with holes

[image]

Comment: thanks! inside polygons are actually holes, is there a way to fix this issue as well?

Comment: look at New in the answer